# why is the NotAuthorizedContent tag not recognized in the app.razor

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I am using the  tag in the app.razor to indicate in all the pages where the user is not authorized to show the same message, but the NotAuthorizedContent tag does not recognize me

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>

    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
    <NotAuthorizedContent>
        <h1>Sorry</h1>
        <p>You're not authorized to reach this page. You may need to log in as a different user.</p>
    </NotAuthorizedContent>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AuthorizeRouteView` :

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">                
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>@L["NotAuthorized"]</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
                
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>@L["NothingAtAddress"]</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Note: I am using a localisation service here for the display text.

Comment: perfect worked for me with <NotAuthorized>
<p> You are not authorized to access this page. </p>
</NotAuthorized>